# Children animation is wrong

Tags: animation

I have two objects one Parent and one Children. I have translate animation on parent, but when I add keyframe to children, children jump to another position in playback. What I am doing wrong? In Blender I can not animate children??

Comment: Can you post the `.blend` or a screenshot and tell us what version of Blender you're using? I'm not having this issue in the latest build of Blender with two parented cubes.

Comment: I found it ! :) I had turn on Visual Keying in Preferences under Editing. Is it normal behaviour with this ON?

Comment: Yep. It can sometimes cause a bunch of issues with constraints and parents.

Comment: From manual: Visual Keying
When an object is using constraints, the objects property value doesnt actually change.
Visual Keying will add keyframes to the object property, with a value based on the visual transformation from the constraint. ... but I still dont understand what does it mean :) Have I report bug with my children parent behaviour? Why there is not any exception.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the parent position affecting the child position, and the child position is relative to the parent position somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I disabled Visual Keying under Editing in User Preferences, problem was solved.